# IllegalArgumentException: Field name doesn't exist on object while doing migration

Tags: realm, realm-migration

I am trying to migrate Realm from version 0 to 1. I have the POJO as follows:

```
@Parcel(implementations = {OrganizerRealmProxy.class},
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = {Organizer.class})
public class Organizer extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long Id;
    private String email;
    private String displayName;
    private Boolean self;
    ...


}
```

And in the migrate method i am doing:

```
RealmObjectSchema organizerSchema = schema.create("Organizer")
                    .addPrimaryKey("Id")
                    .addField("email", String.class)
                    .addField("displayName", String.class)
                    .addField("self", Boolean.class);
```

But i am getting exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field name doesn't exist on object 'Organizer': Id
at io.realm.RealmObjectSchema.checkFieldExists(RealmObjectSchema.java:500)
at io.realm.RealmObjectSchema.addPrimaryKey(RealmObjectSchema.java:297)
at org.granitebaysda.bradapp.utils.RealmMigration.migrate(RealmMigration.java:20)
at io.realm.BaseRealm$2.onResult(BaseRealm.java:578)
at io.realm.RealmCache.invokeWithGlobalRefCount(RealmCache.java:242)
at io.realm.BaseRealm.migrateRealm(BaseRealm.java:565)
at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1062)
at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1051)
at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:231)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:114)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:191)
at org.granitebaysda.bradapp.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:114)at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Realm Version is `0.87.2`

#### UPDATE

After using `addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)` instead of `addPrimaryKey` i started getting another exception:

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field 'id' does
support null values in the existing Realm file. Remove @Required or 
@PrimaryKey from field 'id' or migrate using 
io.realm.internal.Table.convertColumnToNotNullable()
```

My Complete Migration class Code looks like this:

```
public class RealmMigration implements io.realm.RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm dynamicRealm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        // DynamicRealm exposes an editable schema
        RealmSchema schema = dynamicRealm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion == 0) {

            RealmObjectSchema organizerSchema = schema.create("Organizer")
                    .addField("Id", long.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("email", String.class, FieldAttribute.INDEXED)
                    .addField("displayName", String.class)
                    .addField("self", Boolean.class);

            RealmObjectSchema startSchema = schema.create("Start")
                    .addField("Id", long.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("dateTime", String.class)
                    .addField("timeZone", String.class)
                    .addField("date", String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema endSchema = schema.create("End")
                    .addField("Id", long.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("dateTime", String.class)
                    .addField("timeZone", String.class)
                    .addField("date", String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema eventCreatorSchema = schema.create("EventCreator")
                    .addField("email", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("displayName", String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema AttendeeSchema = schema.create("Attendee")
                    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("email", String.class)
                    .addField("displayName", String.class)
                    .addField("organizer", Boolean.class)
                    .addField("self", Boolean.class)
                    .addField("responseStatus", String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema originalStartTimeSchema = schema.create("OriginalStartTime")
                    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("dateTime", String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema recurrenceSchema = schema.create("RecurrenceString")
                    .addField("Id", long.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("recurrence", String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema EventRecurrenceDetailSchema = schema.create("EventRecurrenceDetail")
                    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("freq", int.class)
                    .addField("byDay", int.class)
                    .addField("byDayNum", int.class)
                    .addField("until", String.class)
                    .addField("interval", String.class);

            schema.create("Item")
                    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                    .addField("kind", String.class)
                    .addField("etag", String.class)
                    .addField("status", String.class)
                    .addField("htmlLink", String.class)
                    .addField("created", String.class)
                    .addField("updated", String.class)
                    .addField("summary", String.class)
                    .addField("description", String.class)
                    .addField("location", String.class)
                    .addRealmObjectField("creator", eventCreatorSchema)
                    .addRealmObjectField("organizer", organizerSchema)
                    .addRealmObjectField("start", startSchema)
                    .addRealmObjectField("end", endSchema)
                    .addField("transparency", String.class)
                    .addField("iCalUID", String.class)
                    .addField("sequence", Integer.class)
                    .addRealmListField("attendees", AttendeeSchema)
                    .addField("recurringEventId", String.class)
                    .addRealmObjectField("originalStartTime", originalStartTimeSchema)
                    .addRealmListField("recurrence", recurrenceSchema)
                    .addRealmObjectField("recurrenceDetail", EventRecurrenceDetailSchema);


            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Organizer.java**

```
    public class Organizer extends RealmObject {

        @PrimaryKey
        private long Id;
        @Index
        private String email;
        private String displayName;
        private Boolean self;

...

    }
```

**Start.java**

```
public class Start extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long Id;
    private String dateTime;
    private String timeZone;
    private String date;

    public Start() {
    }
}
```

**End.java**

```
public class End extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long Id;
    @SerializedName("dateTime")
    @Expose
    private String dateTime;
    @SerializedName("timeZone")
    @Expose
    private String timeZone;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;

    public End() {
    }
}
```

**EventCreator.java**

```
public class EventCreator extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String email;
    private String displayName;

    public EventCreator() {
    }
}
```

**Attendee.java**

```
public class Attendee extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String email;
    private String displayName;
    private Boolean organizer;
    private Boolean self;
    private String responseStatus;

    public Attendee() {
    }
}
```

**OriginalStartTime.java**

```
public class OriginalStartTime extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String dateTime;

    public OriginalStartTime() {
    }
}
```

**ReccurenceString.java**

```
public class RecurrenceString extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long Id;
    private String recurrence;

    public RecurrenceString() {
    }
}
```

**EventRecurrenceDetail.java**

```
public class EventRecurrenceDetail extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private int freq;
    private int byDay;
    private int byDayNum;
    private String until;
    private int interval;

    public EventRecurrenceDetail() {
    }
}
```

**Item.java**

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String kind;
    private String etag;
    private String status;
    private String htmlLink;
    private String created;
    private String updated;
    private String summary;
    private String description;
    private String location;
    private EventCreator creator;
    private Organizer organizer;
    private Start start;
    private End end;
    private String transparency;
    private String iCalUID;
    private Integer sequence;
    private RealmList<Attendee> attendees = new RealmList<>();
    private String recurringEventId;
    private OriginalStartTime originalStartTime;
    private RealmList<RecurrenceString> recurrence = new RealmList<>();
    private EventRecurrenceDetail recurrenceDetail;

    public EventRecurrenceDetail getRecurrenceDetail() {
        return recurrenceDetail;
    }

    public Item() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see more of the migration code? Namely, what are you migrating from and what are you migrating to?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```java
RealmObjectSchema organizerSchema = schema.create("Organizer")
                .addField("Id", long.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                .addField("email", String.class)
                .addField("displayName", String.class)
                .addField("self", Boolean.class);
```

`addPrimaryKey` has to be called on an existing field.

---- Updated Jan. 22 2016 Delete specific version of Realm file ----

[`DynamicRealm`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#dynamic-realms) is designed to open Realm file without checking schemas.

If you want to delete version 0 Realm file, you can do something like this:

```java
File file = new File(realmConfig.getPath());
if (file.exist()) {
    DynamicRealm dynamicRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfig);
    long version = dynamicRealm.getVersion();
    dynamicRealm.close();
    if (version == 0) {
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But now i am getting the exception: `RealmMigrationNeededException: Field 'id' does support null values in the existing Realm file. Remove @Required or @PrimaryKey from field 'id' or migrate using io.realm.internal.Table.convertColumnToNotNullable().` while doing `mRealmQuery = Realm.getInstance(config).where(URLs.class).findAll();`

Comment: How did you define the id? `long id`  or `Long.id`? Also, please notice that we had a bug before could cause the problem https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2001 . please use the latest Release :) 0.87.2 at this time.

Comment: It is of type String.

Comment: Version of Realm is `0.87.2`

Comment: I have also added `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED` as the fourth argument to the `addField` method.

Comment: What does your `Organizer` look like now? can you modify your question according to your latest code?

Comment: Sure but there are several models involving, i am updating it now and will try to keep it short.

Comment: Updated, Please have a look. (and it makes longest question i have ever seen :) )

Comment: Did `Item` class exist before? Did you just add the `@PrimaryKey` in the version one? If that is the case, you should use `addPrimaryKey(id)` for item.

Comment: No. All the classes mentioned here do not exist in the first version.

Comment: I have no idea then. Can you share your project with us? to help@realm.io

Comment: And the old version Realm file, to reproduce it.

Comment: Is there any way delete the first version of the Realm to avoid Migration?